# Access is denied after adding STS reference to ASP.NET 4.0 Web Application

Tags: asp.net, wif

I am having a weird problem right now. This is what I did, create a ASP.NET 4.0 Web Application, right click on that application root, Add STS reference. Then F5 run the web application, it gives me a "Access is denied" error. I have tried all my machines. It happens with all the default setup. But I never had a problem in .NET 3.5 web application.
  Can anyone tell me what's the problem?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have seen issues with the STS reference wizard where the web.config was not added properly because of current settings in the web.config.

1) Test your current environment
   With visual studio, create a new MVC 4.0 test application using wizard
   Run test app.
   Right click on project and Add STS reference and use the wizard to complete changes to
   web.config.
   Run Test app again.

2) Back up web.config for your existing MVC 4.0 application  Web.Config.Back
3) Clear out everything in your web.config except for  tags.
4)  Right click on project and Add STS reference and use the wizard to complete changes to
    web.config.
5) Save these changes as Web.Config.STS
6) Restore back your original web.config and the copy the STS elements manually.
7) Retest your application.